# "Error: expected expression before ‘int’" and "Error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘int’"

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner in C and following is a code for Quine-McCluskey Method in which rows of a 2D array are being matched with other rows of the same array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int tally(int *arr[int k],int *arr1[int k],int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
int index,i,j,k;
for (i=a;i<b;i++)
{
    for (j=b;j<c;j++)
    {
        for (k=0;k<d;k++)
        {
            if (arr[i][k]==arr[j][k])
            {
                arr1[index][k]=arr[i][k];
            }
            else
            {
                arr1[index][k]=2;
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
}
return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[8][4],arr1[28][4];
    int no1,one1,two1,three1,four1,index=0,i,j;
    tally((int **)arr, (int **)arr1,0,no1,one1,4);
    tally((int **)arr, (int **)arr1,no1,one1,two1,4);

    for(i=0;i<28;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            printf("arr[i][j]\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I get two errors saying:

```
try2.c:5:20: error: expected expression before ‘int’
 int tally(int *arr[int k],int *arr1[int k],int a, int b, int c, int d)
                ^
try2.c:5:27: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘int’
 int tally(int *arr[int k],int *arr1[int k],int a, int b, int c, int d)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You have more problems than you realize. Whoever/Whatever told you an array of arrays `arr[N][M]` and a pointer-to-pointer `int **arr`are synonymous was wrong. If it was a book, burn it. If it was an instructor, drop the class. The forced cast is your first clue something isn't right.

Comment: The code, as you wrote it, is meaningless syntactically and semantically in quite a few places. You need to read a good book on C. You can't just write semi-random syntactic constructs that look 
"close enough" to C code and then ask people to "fix" them for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```c
 int tally(int *arr[int k],int *arr1[int k],int a, int b, int c, int d)
```

to

```c
 int tally(int k, int *arr, int *arr1, int a, int b, int c, int d)
```

Don´t forget to adjust your function calls!

EDIT:

I see, your code does not examine `k` so just change it to:

```c
 int tally(int *arr[], int *arr1[], int a, int b, int c, int d)
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to a pointer is not the same thing as an array of arrays. You shouldn't be having to cast the arguments to your function.

If your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays (which is in the C99 standard), you could do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int tally(size_t rows_s, size_t rows_l, size_t cols, 
          int small[rows_s][cols], int large[rows_l][cols])
{
    // ...
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    size_t cols = 4;
    size_t rows_s = 8, rows_l = 28;
    int small[rows_s][cols], large[rows_l][cols];

    tally(rows_s,rows_l,cols,small,large);

    return 0;
}
```

I have removed the other arguments as it wasn't clear what they were for. In general, I would recommend using self-explanatory names for your arguments, as it all gets a bit confusing otherwise.